# Why you can't see online status of others if you hide yours?

Tags: facebook, whatsapp

In many apps, like Facebook or WhatsApp, you cannot see online status of others if you hide yours (WhatsApp) or disable chat (Facebook website/Messenger).

Why and how this should be considered a security measure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not, it's merely a fair use policy/scenario.  You get a privacy benefit (seeming to be offline), but you have to pay a price (not knowing when others are online).  Technically, they could tell you when others are online when you're invisible (like how skype does it), but Facebook/Whatsapp chooses not to.